# Installing true type fonts in MiKTeX and cannot find source file

Tags: fonts, miktex, truetype

I would like to use a TrueType font in pdfLatex. I am using MiKTeX 2.9.

I am following these instructions:  http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm
(If there are updated instructions, please let me know.)

When I got to this step:

```
 Start=>Programs=>MiKTeX=>Maintenance=>Refresh Filename Database
```

I used these two instead

```
 Start, Programs, MiKTeX 2.9, Maintenance, Settings
   General, Refresh FNDB
 Start, Programs, MiKTeX 2.9, Maintenance (Admin), Settings (Admin)
   General, Refresh FNDB
```

Now I am at this step:

```
 tex testfont
 dvips testfont.dvi
```

And I get this error:

```
C:\download\fontTest>tex testfont
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\plain\base\testfont.tex"

Name of the font to test = eckeys
Now type a test command (\help for help):)
*\table\eject\init
[1]
Name of the font to test = eckeysb
Now type a test command (\help for help):
*\table\eject\init
[2]
Name of the font to test = eckeysi
Now type a test command (\help for help):
*\bye
[3]
Output written on testfont.dvi (3 pages, 21676 bytes).
Transcript written on testfont.log.

C:\download\fontTest>dvips testfont.dvi
This is dvips(k) 5.993 Copyright 2013 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2014.11.29:0941' -> testfont.ps
Trying to make PK font reckeys at 600 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The reckeys source file could not be found.
Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makepk: PK font reckeys could not be created.
dvips: Font reckeys not found; characters will be left blank.
Trying to make PK font reckeysb at 600 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The reckeysb source file could not be found.
Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makepk: PK font reckeysb could not be created.
dvips: Font reckeysb not found; characters will be left blank.

.



[1] [2]
[3]
```

It appears that TeX can find the fonts because "tex testfont" will complain if I use a font name that does not exist.  However, dvips and miktex-makepk cannot.

Would you please tell me how to proceed, or please point me to a newer document that explains how to use TrueType fonts in pdflatex?

Comment: I do not use MiKTeX. However, those instructions seem... odd. It is not possible to use `.ttf` with LaTeX without converting them i.e. you cannot use them directly. (As far as I know.) You *can* use them directly with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Is XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX an option? You could use the font without needing to mess around in that case. Installing fonts for use with (pdf)LaTeX is perfectly possible but it is not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks cfr.  Moving to XeLaTeX worked for me.  I am using Windows 7.  These are custom True Type fonts which I am required to use, and none of the built-in fonts matched in all characters.

First I clicked on the .ttf files so Windows would install them.

Then in my .tex file, I removed all the font lines that looked like this (which were needed for pdfLaTeX but caused XeLaTeX to hang)

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{uarial}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

Then I added the lines needed by XeLaTeX

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{MyCustomFont}
```

Thanks for the tip of trying XeLaTeX. The instructions for installing a font on pdfLaTeX were very complicated.  XeLaTeX was much simpler once I corrected the \usepackage lines shown above. XeLaTeX seems to work very well in creating a PDF with the correct True Type font.